# EasySlider 1.7. Getting the images dynamicly via PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, easyslider

So i have this EasySlider 1.7 and loads of images i want to show in there, problem is that right now i need to edit html file each time i change images or add/delete.

is it possible to get images from folder and and show them in EasySlider with single script.
example : script goes to image folder and getting first image and putting it to slider.

i tried some php scripts , and best result i got was when php script pulled whole image folder  and displayed them all at once messing up the slider.

i hope i made my question clear, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the glob() to get an array of the files in a certain folder like this:

```
$files=glob("/path/*.*"); // an array of the files in the folder
foreach($files as $file) // loops through the array and prints out the files
   echo $file;
```

Put this in the suitable place with the EasySlider and then you won't need to edit the html everytime you add/delete files.

Comment: Probably should make sure that the file extension is within a set of allowable image extensions before dumping out the files

Comment: `<li> <?php $files=glob("images/*.jpg");
foreach($files as $file) 
   echo "$file" ?></li>`  i put this code into where the images should appear but it displayed all image file names in slide. as i understand i should get some code what is making it to display images 1 by 1 ?

Comment: yea it was typo, i recently started building website so im pretty noob in this area. last time i was doing such things was when people was looking cool animated *.gif-s in internets :D         `<div id="slider">
<ul> 
    
<li> <?php $files=glob("images/*.jpg");
foreach($files as $file) 
   echo "$file" ?></li>
</ul>
</div>` atm it looks like this, i am experimenting with that code

Comment: Try this: <?php $files=glob("images/*.jpg"); foreach($files as $file) echo "<li><img src='".$file."' alt='' /></li>"; ?>

Comment: hmm its kind of working now, thank you. i will test around and see what is happening, how to rate this answer now :) nvm Vote Up requires 15 reputation